# Responsive multicolumn MultiSelectListBox

Tags: vaadin, responsive

I have a `MultiSelectListBox<String>` with ~20 items. The `MultiSelectListBox` must be responsive so depending on the screen wide it must be displayed either in one, two or three columns. How to achieve this in a clean vaadin way without css hacking etc? Thanks.

Used vaadin version 23.1.0.rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (-t yet) some API to do that with just some theme variant.  So one option is to [create your own
theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/ds-resources/customization/custom-theme)
and then provide some styling for the `vaadin-list-box` in
`.../themes/my-theme/components/vaadin-list-box.css`.  E.g.

```css
:host {
    --responsive-size: 20em;
}

:host {
    width: var(--responsive-size);
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    :host {
        width: calc(2*var(--responsive-size));
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    :host {
        width: calc(3*var(--responsive-size));
    }
}

[part="items"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

[part="items"] ::slotted(vaadin-item) {
    width: var(--responsive-size);
}
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to make that a theme of your
component (then use `:host([theme~="responsive"])` for selectors) and
adjust the width and the responsive steps. See [Styling
Components](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/ds-resources/customization/styling-components)